# How to display the live online user in the system using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I am showing live online user using CodeIgniter.

I tried some code but I am confused now.

Reference video. I learn from this video

https://www.webslesson.info/2017/08/display-online-users-using-php-mysql-with-ajax-jquery.html

**OR**

Step:1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAG3w8l8lL8

Step:2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L__8vVJT57U

Here is my code.

**Login Password verify**

If the password is correct then It will insert the time and user id in the database.

```
    if ($result) {             
    if(password_verify($password,$result->password))
        {
            $data_login= array('emp_id' =>$result->id ,'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))));
            $this->db->insert('tbl_current_login',$data_login);  
            $last_id=$this->db->insert_id();
            if (!empty($last_id)) {
            $active_user_session = array('id' => $result->id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);
            $this->session->set_userdata('active_user_session',$active_user_session);
            return $result;

                }

                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }       
    }

    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I updated the script on the index page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   <?php 
    if ($this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']) {?>
    function update_user_activity(){
       var active_time='update_time';
           $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Employee_control/update_login_time",
                method:"POST",
                data:{active_time:active_time},
                success:function(data){
                 //alert(data);
                   }
                   });
                 }
              setInterval(function(){
               update_user_activity()
                 },3000);
              <?php
               }?>
             });
```

**Employee controller**

```
public function update_login_time(){
     $active_time=trim($this->input->post('active_time'));
     if (isset($active_time)) {
          $this->Employee_model->update_last_login();
     }
}
```

**Employee model**

```
public function update_last_login(){
      $data = array(
                   'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))),
                   'emp_id' =>$this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']
                );

    $this->db->where('emp_id', $this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']);
    $this->db->update('tbl_current_login', $data); 
    }
```

Now My issue is, 
if user login first time then login time will insert in the table and if user login second time then it will insert again new login time. Right?. There is some issue with an update. It's updating all the last_activity time which is related to the id. If this is true then at the end of the day how can we identify the total number of hours user logged in? and how can we check the history of the user if we update the all the last_activity time?

[image]

I just want to display the live online user in the system.
Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: why you not using realtime services like pusher , firebase , socket etc. ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, I don't have any idea about that. so I found the video to do. do you have any link or any video to resolved this? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you confirm that the screenshot above means user with `emp_id = 8` has been logged in three times and the query should only update the latest `tbl_current_login` where `emp_id = 8` and `login_id=5` ?

Comment: @ekad, Yes, that's correct user 8 logged in 3 times, and It's updated all 3 records because of I used the query. but I don't think so that is the correct way.

Comment: Try to change `$active_user_session = array('id' => $result->id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);` to this: `$active_user_session = array('id' => $last_id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);` in your login verify method.

Comment: @ekad, Yes, I tried but the same issue, It's updating all the records. I think there is some issue in the "Employee model" code that code is updating all the records Please check in the question

Comment: In your model code, change `'emp_id' =>$this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']` to `'login_id' =>$this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']` and change `$this->db->where('emp_id',` to `$this->db->where('login_id',`, see if it helps.

Comment: @ekad, Oh! yes, this time it's updating the last record. Give me some time to check more

Comment: @ekad, Yes, it's working perfectly. Please update your answer. so that in future I can refer you answer.

Comment: Done, answer added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `active_user_session` session data using the below code in your login verify method

```
$active_user_session = array('id' => $result->id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);
$this->session->set_userdata('active_user_session',$active_user_session);
```

If the user id is 8, then the value of `$result->id` above will be 8 and that also means `$this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']` in your model code below will be 8

```
public function update_last_login(){
    $data = array(
               'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))),
               'emp_id' =>$this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']
            );

    $this->db->where('emp_id', $this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']);
    $this->db->update('tbl_current_login', $data); 
}
```

Assuming current time is `2018-09-16 08:59:16`, your model code above generates and executes the following query

```
UPDATE tbl_current_login
SET last_activity = '2018-09-16 08:59:16', emp_id = 8
WHERE emp_id = 8
```

However it's the wrong query because each `tbl_current_login` record is added every time a user logs in and what you really want to update is only the latest record for that particular user. This is the query you're looking for

```
UPDATE tbl_current_login
SET last_activity = '2018-09-16 08:59:16'
WHERE login_id = 5
```

To get the correct query, change this portion of code in your login verify method

```
$data_login = array('emp_id' =>$result->id ,'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))));
$this->db->insert('tbl_current_login',$data_login);  
$last_id=$this->db->insert_id();
if (!empty($last_id)) {
    $active_user_session = array('id' => $result->id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);
    $this->session->set_userdata('active_user_session',$active_user_session);
    return $result;
}
```

to this

```
$data_login = array('emp_id' =>$result->id ,'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))));
$this->db->insert('tbl_current_login',$data_login);  
$last_id=$this->db->insert_id();
if (!empty($last_id)) {
    // $last_id is the id of the tbl_current_login record inserted above
    // pass it to the array below
    $active_user_session = array('id' => $last_id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);
    $this->session->set_userdata('active_user_session',$active_user_session);
    return $result;
}
```

then change your model code to this

```
public function update_last_login(){
    $data = array(
                   'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa')))
                );

    $this->db->where('login_id', $this->session->userdata['active_user_session']['id']);
    $this->db->update('tbl_current_login', $data); 
}
```