# How to calculate the total time logged in the system?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and I am calculating the total time from the dates.

Explanation:

What I am doing is, Every login I am inserting the last_Ativity date and time in the database using below code.

```
$data_login= array('emp_id' =>$result->id ,'last_activity' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))));
$this->db->insert('tbl_current_login',$data_login);
```

last_activity time continuously updating if the user still in the system . (I am using ajax to update the datetime. I haven't shared that code).

Now I have to calculate the total time of the specific user for a single day(current date).

For example- emp_id `26` logged in twice so I have to calculate the time

```
First-time login date and time:-2018-09-17 07:27:55
Second-time login date and time:- 2018-09-17 07:35:22
```

It will increase depending upon how many time the user logged in.

I am confused about the time. Am I on the right path to calculate the total hour login in the system? 
Should I use an MYSQL query or PHP to calculate? I need some idea.
Would you help me out in this?

[image]

Comment: How do you calculate total time with out a logout time?

Comment: I will need to take a few assumptions for my answer, you need to be more specific... how do you know the ussr is not logged, afer X time? by a cron job? total time per day?

Comment: @dmikester1, Thanks for the reply. I haven't created yet. So I have to create a one more column for logout? right?

Comment: Well, you could just create another column called something like `activity` and set it to either 1 or 0, for either login or logout.

Comment: And what happens if the user never clicks "log out"?  Does the system automatically log them out after x minutes?

Comment: You can't without a range of time, you only have the time they were last active, not the time they started to be active.  But you could save yourself some work by saving the time they are active in seconds when you do the Ajax call this would be fairly easy to do just before updating the last active time, calculate the difference in seconds and add that to an additional column you would add in the DB, it won't be 100% accurate but this kind of thing never is.

Comment: @dmikester1, your last comment about log out. That is also a good point for me. I haven't tried that. I am a new learning to learning

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, What I did is, I am adding the last actiity time in the database for each login to display the number of user login in the system. now I have to calculate the number of hours the user was in the system

Comment: @dmikester1, do you have any link or any video where I can learn your points?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  But I'm sure you can find plenty of examples on Stack Overflow and Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do

> last_activity time continuously updating if the user still in the system . (I am using ajax to update the datetime. I haven't shared that code).

Before you update the row.

- check if a row for activity exists

  - if it does, get the timestamps for the date and subtract the current time (the one you are changing last_activity to, from the one stored in the DB) take that number and add it to an integer column named something like elapsed time (you would have to add this to the DB)
  - if not then enter a row with 0 elapsed time ( depending how you put the first row in, maybe on login) this may never be an issue.

For the timestamps, you would do a select to get the current row. Take the datetime field and use either

```
 $time = strtotime($row['last_activity']);
```

OR

```
 $time = (new DateTime($row['last_activity']))->getTimestamp();
```

Then you simply do the same thing to the date you are going to replace that with and then subtract to get the difference in seconds.

```
$elapsed = time() - $time;
```

And then add that to the current rows value, and save it.  This way you can keep track of a running total in seconds of the time they spend during that session.

Then when you need to count the total time its a simple matter of doing

```
SELECT SUM(elapsed_time) FROM {table} WHERE DATE(last_Ativity) = :date
```

If you were dealing with just two date time fields in the DB it would be easier to just get the difference of those, but sense you already have code to constantly update the last active field this would require less work in the long run IMO.

**Option2**

The other option is to add another Datetime field to put a start time or login time in.  Then when you query you can convert them to their timestamps and subtract to get the difference.

This makes the SQL harder (when doing the SUM ), I can't really think off the top of my head how I would calculate the elapsed time on multiple rows and then sum them up. But it does simplify the PHP quite a bit.  So which ever way works best for what you need.  Think about if you need the utility to know when they logged in, or if you just want an easier way to calculate the time they spend.

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need time to implement your answer with my code.

Comment: Sure, but you understand that right now by changing the last active datetime you lose information.  So you either need a starting datetime, or to keep track of the actual time.

Comment: What I am trying to achive is, I have a system to check how my users are logged in the system. So I check this link and update my code.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350853/how-to-display-the-live-online-user-in-the-system-using-codeigniter        now I have to calculate the total hour or how may hours they are loggin or if user still login that also show the total time

Comment: Personally I would take control of saving the Session and save it in the DB, it's a bit harder to initially setup but you could probably kill a few birds with the same stone, as the saying goes.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: So I thought, using last_activity I can find the total hours

Comment: Only if you know when they started.  Knowing the last time they accessed the site is not enough.  Think if you had a timeclock at work, you punch in and punch out, if you only punch out they cant figure out your hours because there is no punch in time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180225/discussion-between-user9437856-and-artisticphoenix).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only log happens based on user actions, and so, after 15 minutes (for example) the user is assumed logged out
And assuming you'd want daily total, the solution should be something like this:

```
    SELECT
     first.emp_id, 
     SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,first.last_acivity, DATE_ADD(IFNULL(last.last_acivity, first.last_acivity), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))) as logged_minutes

FROM

(
SELECT
 la1.*
    FROM
    last_acivity la1
    LEFT JOIN last_acivity la2 ON
    la1.emp_id = la2.emp_id AND la1.last_acivity < la2.last_acivity
    AND la2.activity =< @date0
    WHERE
     la1.last_acivity >= @date0
  AND la2.login_id IS NULL
) first

LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT
 la1.*
    FROM
    last_acivity la1
    LEFT JOIN last_acivity la2 ON
    la1.emp_id = la2.emp_id AND la1.last_acivity > la2.last_acivity
    AND la2.activity =< @date0
    WHERE
     la1.last_acivity >= @date0
  AND la2.login_id IS NULL
) last 
ON
first.emp_id = last.emp_id

    GROUP BY
     emp_id
```

In this query need to set the date seperately:

```
SET @date0  = DATE(NOW()) ;
```

To get the first record of the day, or the last, we need to LEFT join the table to itself, on the same emp_id BUT witn with an inequality, which will get for each emp record its ancestors or predecessors
When we add the NULL condition we bring the we get the edge case: first or last

What's left then is just calculating the minutes between the 2 tables

Since I assumed no log out record occurs, I treated the case when the first and last logins are the same, or no last login